# Resolving Java thread visibility and concurrency error using Map compute

Tags: java, thread-safety, java-threads

I use Java 8. I have an event handler that accepts events with a high rate, (n per second) and I want to flush them out to storage when I get so many of them (in this simplified example 1000)

Do I have a visibility error on line 25 `myCache.get(event.getKey()).add(event.getBean());` ?
Should I synchronize on `handleEvent()` method?

```
public class myClass extends MySimpleEventHanlder {
    private Map<String, List<MyBean>> myCache;
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    public void MyClass() {
        myCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<MyBean>>();
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {

            for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, List<MyBean>>> it = myCache.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                Map.Entry<String, List<MyBean>> entry = it.next();
                if (entry.getValue().size() >= 1000) {
                    it.remove();
                    //do some more processing , flush to storage
                }
            }
        }, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {

        if (myCachetCache.containsKey(event.getKey())) {
            myCache.get(event.getKey()).add(event.getBean());
        }
        else{
            List<MyBean> beans = new ArrayList<MyBeans>();
            beans.add(event.getBean());
            myCache.put(event.key, beans);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of java? can't you use compute instead of mutating the list?

Comment: Nathan Hughes, I use Java 8 , what do you mean by using "compute" ?

Comment: "visibility problem" - the compiler would complain! ...if you mean "concurrency problem" - rather not, because it is a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: compute is a method on CHM https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-

Comment: Is `handleEvent` itself used by multiple threads or do you have a single event dispatch thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely have visibility problems: you add items into an ArrayList in one thread, and read the size() from that ArrayList in another thread, with no synchronization in between.

Another problem is that the key may get removed between the calls to `myCache.containsKey` and `myCache.get`. This would cause a NullPointerException. That could be solved by using compute, which is guaranteed to be atomic.

```
    myCache.compute(event.getKey(), (key, value) -> {
        if (value == null) {
            value = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        value.add(event.getBean());
        return value;
    });
```